# How do you pass a UserCreationForm field into input field by just using template?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use bootstrap's input style and wondering if I can pass user creation form fields onto input without having to create a custom class. I've tried this which didn't work:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input name="{{ form.username }}" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: You can use [django-bootstrap4](https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap4) or [crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Use This:

forms.py

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-4','required':True,'placeholder':'Username'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-4','required':True,'placeholder':'Email'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control mb-4','required':True,'placeholder':'Password'}),
        }
        fields = ('username','email','password',)
```

html

```
   {{ form.username }}
    {{ form.email }}
    {{ form.password }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-info mt-3 btn-block waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Register</button>
```